# Unable to play videos from SD-CARD using react-native-video

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to play videos via SD-CARD using react-native-video. I am using [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) package to interface the SD-CARD. But i am unable to play any videos. I have manually given storage permissions to the app and AndroidManifest.xml already contains read-write user permissions.

```
    <Video
        url={{
          uri:
            "file://" +
            RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardDir +
            "/Video/videofile1.mp4"
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
```

I tried using "source" instead of "url", many suggested to append "file://" to the start, but i got no success yet.

SD-CARD used is SanDisk Ultra microSDHC UHS-I card.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited (admittedly) experience of rn-fetch-blob isn't it a promise?

So instead of having the promise directly in the url of your Video component you would take advantage of reactive state! And have....

(note: I'm using vanilla react state, replace with whatever you use, redux etc.)

```
state = {
  url: false
}

.......then later in your render/return:
{
 url 
    ? <Video url={this.state.url} />
    : <SomeLoaderComponentYouDefine />
}
```

Then have a separate function with your rn-fetch-blob logic, possibly triggered on componentDidMount() (without seeing more code it's hard to determine the best route). This way the loading will be handled properly. The 'SomeLoaderComponentYouDefine' can be the [react native activity indicator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator)

Also it would be useful to know which OS it's not working on, both, only one etc. There are a few open issues relating to permissions in android specifically. In my limited personal experience

for iOS:

```
DocumentDir
```

for android:

```
SDCardApplicationDir
```

generally works.